# Shake water and seed oil: color and density

Tags: density, density-operator

These days I am spraying the leaves of my garden, to prevent insects, mixing strongly water and soya oil.  The color has become all white.

**Soy oil** has a relative density of $0.915 \div 0.925$ kg/dm$^3$ and the **water** is $1.000$ kg/dm$^3$.

The white colour I believe is due to the strong mixing that breaks the bonds of soya oil and water.

Is there a physical or mathematical method, starting with the densities, to justify the white colour?

Comment: @downvoter: Is there a reason for a downvote for my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is the [Tyndall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect).

> The Tyndall effect is light scattering by particles in a colloid or in
> a very fine suspension. Also known as Willis–Tyndall scattering, it is
> similar to Rayleigh scattering, in that the intensity of the scattered
> light is inversely proportional to the fourth power of the wavelength,
> so blue light is scattered much more strongly than red light. An
> example in everyday life is the blue colour sometimes seen in the
> smoke emitted by motorcycles, in particular two-stroke machines where
> the burnt engine oil provides these particles.

Comment: I thank you for your precious answer. I have seen the link and I not known this Tyndall effect. Does not exists a mathematical formula that explain this fenomen? Thank you very much. I not understood because when I ask a question I have often downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote.

Comment: I'm always happy when I give an upvote. You can see my profile on TeX.SE. 